# check if a user is logged in successfully Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a database level `after logon or servererror` trigger, how do I check if the user is logged in or there is a servererror? One solution is to break it down to two triggers but I need to do it using a single trigger.

Comment: These are two completely different things, Why do you want just one trigger? There won’t be any savings in combining the logic into one trigger.

Comment: @AndrewSayer Assignment requirement...

Comment: A connected user's session will appear in `v$session`.

Comment: *"Assignment requirement."* Always depressing when school work demands a ridiculous implementation

Answer (score 1):

```
    IF ( sys.server_error(1) = 1017 OR sys.server_error(1) = 1005 ) THEN
        --handles unsuccessfull login
    ENDIF;
    IF (ORA_SYSEVENT = "LOGON") THEN
        -- handles successfull login
    ENDIF;
```